# Third nested blank iframe is invisible

Tags: javascript, iframe

I ran into a very surprising behaviour and I can't figure out what it comes from : I build 3 nested blank iframes in javascript but the third one is invisible.

Tested in Chrome. Here is the code : (https://jsfiddle.net/44uL3bku/)

```
(function() {
    var i1 = document.createElement('iframe');
    i1.width  = 315;
    i1.height = 300;
    i1.addEventListener('load', function() {
        this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = 'IFRAME 1<br>';
        var i2 = this.contentDocument.createElement('iframe');
        i2.width  = '100%';
        i2.height = '100%';
        i2.addEventListener('load', function() {
            this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = 'IFRAME 2<br>';
            var i3 = this.contentDocument.createElement('iframe');
            i3.width  = '100%';
            i3.height = '100%';
            i3.addEventListener('load', function() {
                this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = 'IFRAME 3<br>';
            });
            this.contentDocument.body.appendChild(i3);
            var i4 = this.contentDocument.createElement('iframe');
            i4.width  = '100%';
            i4.height = '100%';
            i4.addEventListener('load', function() {
                this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = 'IFRAME 3<br>';
            });
            this.contentDocument.body.appendChild(i4);
            var bottom = document.createElement('div');
            bottom.innerHTML = 'bottom';
            this.contentDocument.body.appendChild(bottom);
        });
        this.contentDocument.body.appendChild(i2);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(i1);
})();
```

Just to be clear : the DOM tree is properly set, and the "IFRAME 3" is actually there. But it is just not displayed.

Also it only concerns blank iframes. As soon as there is a regular src everything works fine again.

Any idea ?
Thank you all !